# Testing Rails nested controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, functional-testing

I have an `Admin` model which can manage `Organization`s.
I have an `AdminController` with a simple `index` action and a child `Admin::OrganizationsController` controller which I'm trying to test.

The test for the canonical `show` action on this child controller passes without errors:

```
describe "GET show" do
  it "assigns the requested organization as @organization" do
    org = FactoryGirl.create(:organization)
    get :show, id: org.id # <---- this works
    expect(assigns(:organization)).to eq(org)
  end
end
```

but when I try to test the `destroy` action, I get an error I'm not able to understand (hence resolve):

```
describe "DELETE destroy" do
  it "destroys the requested organization" do
    org = FactoryGirl.create(:organization)
    delete :destroy, id: org.id # <---- (I tried to use org.id.to_param, unsuccessfully)
    # ...rest of the test
  end
end
```

with error:

```
Failure/Error: expect { delete :destroy, id: org.id }.to change(Organization, :count).by(-1)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `organizations_url' for #<Admin::OrganizationsController:0x007fefe1622248>
```

I suspect this has to do with my controller being "nested" (it needs something like `admin_organizations_url` I guess).

Any help?

(additional side infos: Rails 4.0.1, rspec 3.0.0.beta1)

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, what does the `Admin::OrganizationsController` look like?  I'm wondering if you're referencing the above helper in that controller, which is causing the test to blow up...

Comment: @CDub It's a standard scaffolded controller, with the canonical `index`, `show`, `edit`, `destroy` etc. actions. Actually all its content has been "stolen" from the scaffolded `OrganizationController`.

Comment: That could be your problem then...  If you didn't change the controller's scaffolding, it's still referencing `organizations_url` instead of `admin_organizations_url`...

Comment: @CDub Yep, that was it! I changed most of the scaffolded parts that interfered with the controller being a nested one, but I completely missed this one! Thank you.

Comment: Good deal.  I'll post an answer.  Feel free to accept. :)  On second thought, just noticed you answered your own answer.  You get the credit - well done. :)

Comment: @CDub Thanks for the help! Sorry for posting the answer myself, I kind of felt idiotic for this question and I didn't want to involve you any further :).

Comment: Don't apologize for posting your own answer.  You figured it out yourself - therefore you get credit for the answer.  Thus why I +1'd your answer.  Well done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inspired" by CDub's comment, I took a look at the `destroy` action in `Admin::OrganizationController`, which looked like this:

```
def destroy
  @organization.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to organizations_url } # <--- has to be admin_organizaions_url
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

I didn't pay attention to the `respond_to` block **at all**.